# Debug errors are not detailed enough

Tags: apex

I am trying to debug an error I receive inside an APEX function.

Even if I use the finest filter on the debug logs, I don't get enough details, and that makes me go to the code, instead of seen the needed object.

The error I get is a NullPointer - that's ok, but I would like to know which field is the error one.

[image]

I don't have a problem going to the code, but if I can see the "field" in the call of the function, that's a great time saver.

Part of the corresponding code is:

```
    .....
    jsGen.writeStringField('PO', getStringValueIfNull(m_opp.PO_Number__c));
    jsGen.writeStringField('SF_oppty_id', m_opp.Id);

    // If the oppty owner is dummy dlr: apacdlr, eurodlr, latamdlr
    // need to set the NS owner as the Bill to Account (accound dealer)
    jsGen.writeNumberField('Owner ID', getNSEmployeeID(m_opp.owner.NS_Employee_Id__c));
    jsGen.writeStringField('Opportunity Name', m_opp.Name );
    jsGen.writeNumberField('Location', getLocationId(m_opp.owner.Sales_Person_Region__c));


    // Get the correct SalesOrder Form to use in NS
    jsGen.writeStringField('Custom Form', getSalesOrderForm(m_opp.owner.NS_Subsidiary__c));

    //Custom Form": " Optitex Sales Order” for Israel and US, “Optitex Sales Order - India Subsidiary” for India
    // Select the correct Sales Order Form
/* * Change to call method
    if (m_opp.owner.NS_Subsidiary__c == 'Parent Company : Consolidated ILS : India Adjustment : Optitex India pvt Ltd')
    {
        jsGen.writeStringField('Custom Form', 'Optitex Sales Order - India Subsidiary');
    } else if (m_opp.owner.NS_Subsidiary__c == 'Parent Company : Consolidated ILS : Optitex USA Inc')
    {
        jsGen.writeStringField('Custom Form', 'Optitex Sales Order - Invoice - USA');
    } else jsGen.writeStringField('Custom Form', 'Optitex Sales Order - No');
*/        
 ......
```

Any ideas ?

BTW: I don't check ALL fields for NULL, since some fields CAN not have a null today, and the data is probably old.

Answer (score 1):

I won't argue with you that the logging isn't as helpful as it might be when debugging Apex code. But going to the code is going to be necessary to fix the problem, so personally I don't see that as a big deal.

The stack trace reported when a NullPointerException happens usually contains all the information you need to track down the problem field.

Here is an example (different flavour of NullPointerException):

```
05:34:59.520 (3520734174)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to
de-reference a null object

Class.cve.PaymentCalculator.doCalculate: line 1122, column 1
Class.cve.PaymentCalculator.calculate: line 1095, column 1
Class.cve.PaymentCalculationController.doCalculate: line 1365, column 1
Class.cve.PaymentCalculationController.calculatePayments: line 1245, column 1
```

where the first line number (and class name) is exactly the line of code the exception occurred in and so generally identifies the field that the problem is with. If it is a piece of code where various values are passed in, where the code is called from (the next line number and class name) is available and so on up the call stack so you can usually figure out the field in that case too.

The bottom line is that the stack trace and its line numbers are hugely helpful in diagnosing problems and it is a pity that problems are often posted on this site without that information.

Comment: thank you Keith, I'm well aware. In my case, the problem does NOT lie in the code. It's a bad data issue. Identifying the correct function will help solve the problem. I am looking for a way to: 'debug.print("Value is: = " & field.value)' or something like this.

Comment: OK. But I don't follow why knowing the problem originates at a line such as `jsGen.writeStringField('Opportunity Name', m_opp.Name );` (based on the stack trace line numbers) isn't enough to identify that it is the `Name` field that is null.

Comment: I am trying to avoid to go to the code. Just to save an extra minute if possible. The debug does not tell me the field name. Only the line (which helps).

Comment: Debug logs are only as accurate to the nearest line. You'll still have to know where the error lies. That can often be more complicated than it seems.